# How do I configure Broadcom Wifi Drivers on Gobolinux?

Tags: wifi, drivers

## 2016-06-19 - Initial Post

I'm having trouble setting up my wifi connection on GoboLinux. I already installed the propietary broadcom drivers. The wifi module is now recognized, at least.

Using `iwconfig wlan0` gives me the following output:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

That means there must be some kind of wifi module build into my laptop. (Using Windows it works btw.)

`lspci -k` shows me the name of the Network controller.

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device 04b5
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

The firmware is being loaded - `dmesg | grep b43`:

```
[    8.127113] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)
[    8.142216] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1
[ 1339.940316] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[ 1777.008290] b43-phy0: Radio hardware status changed to DISABLED
[ 1782.025291] b43-phy0: Radio hardware status changed to ENABLED
[ 2247.468296] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
```

I am not able to scan for existing wifi networks and also cannot connect to one. What am I missing?

## 2016-06-20 - Edit, Print System Information

Here is my System Information per `uname -a`:

```
Linux Arbeits-PC 3.14.2-Gobo #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat May 3 22:59:40 GMT 2014 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please add the output of `uname -a`

Comment: I added the System Information (`uname -a`)

Answer (score 0):

The `bcm4312` is [supported](http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#supported) by the `b43` driver.

Install the `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` package .

Unload driver:

```
modprobe -r b43-pci-bridge
modprobe -r ssb
```

Load the `b43` driver :

```
modprobe b43
```

Comment: i installed it via recipe, but i still cannot find any network.